# Why is Facebook Open Graph ignoring $_GET Method?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I have searched for hours and have come up empty. I'm sure it is something easy that I am missing but I really need help.

If you go to the link below, you will see that the video id is printed out on the page.

http://www.daystar.com/fb_opengraph_test2.php?video=123

When I load that URL into the Debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and click on "Scraped URL - See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL", I don't see the output of my GET.

Here is my basic test code:

```
<head>
    <title>Testing <?php echo $_GET['video'];?></title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Open Graph META Tags"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.daystar.com/fb_opengraph_test2.php"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.daystar.com/wp-content/uploads/daystar-logo-1.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Testing"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is a test"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "Testing URL - video=" . $_GET['video'];?>
</body>
```

Please help. This has been driving me nuts all day.

Comment: How do you "load the URL into the debugger"?

Comment: I am clicking on the link above and pasting in the URL listed.

Comment: I do not have a Facebook account but have indeed worked with the API previously. Could you provide a screenshot or anything of the like?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OzyZS.jpg

Comment: This has to be a server side issue. I am using WP Engine to host my account and its like the call over to them is getting truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the Apache Access log, I realized that this was a server setup error. I was getting a 301 Redirect in the log. Apparently there was a setting which causes bots to redirect such as the facebookexternalhit/1.1 bot being used by Facebook.

Thanks for all the help. I'm leaving this Question here in case someone else has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your og:url is http://www.daystar.com/fb_opengraph_test2.php without GET. Facebook will load the og:url and treat it as a redirect. And then the GET is empty. You need to change your og:url to `http://www.daystar.com/fb_opengraph_test2.php?video=<?php echo $_GET['video'];?>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's a problem that I can't fix because it is not loading the GET. Cause the cache takes so long, I created another example: http://www.daystar.com/fb_opengraph_test44.php?video=123

You will see that it is throwing an error cause the video ID isn't loading.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing: i.stack.imgur.com/OzyZS.jpg

Comment: When I go to http://www.daystar.com/fb_opengraph_test2.php?video=123 I see `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.daystar.com/fb_opengraph_test2.php"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an additional Tag

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.daystar.com/fb_opengraph_test44.php?video=123" />
```

and check again:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.daystar.com%2Ffb_opengraph_test44.php%3Fvideo%3D123

Comment: It's the dynamic video parameter that won't load so I can't add that link. Here is what I am doing. Just a simple test. 
Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing: i.stack.imgur.com/OzyZS.jpg

Comment: I don't understand... You can also dynamically produce that link with PHP

Comment: CHeck out this screenshot. My PHP code should be reading in the URL variable, but FB Open Graph just ignores it. I feel like I'm going crazy here. lol 
i.stack.imgur.com/OzyZS.jpg

Comment: I saw your screenshot! I was suggesting that you additionally define the canonical URL manually, because that's what is not acknowledged by the FB scraper, which can be seen in the scraper output.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-canonical